# Parsing XML file in Android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file in my application which contains arrays of tags. On parsing using XMLPullParser some tags which are closing in next line, there is addaed an extra line.

```
 Example: 
        </PaymentMode>
      <PaymentMode>
            <Type>Gift Card</Type>
           <Amount>24.00
           </Amount>
        </PaymentMode>
       <PaymentMode>
             <Type>Paypal</Type>
             <Amount>9.00
            </Amount>
        </PaymentMode>
```

Here when  is parsed, an extra line is added between type and amount and I get:

```
      Type: Gift Card

      Amount: 24
      Type: Paypal

      Amount: 9.00
```

How do I remove this extra line?

Answer (score 0):

With XmlPullParser you can parse XMl file..

private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
private XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();